# Зачем нужны condition_variable если есть yield? C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Решил, что дорос до многопоточности в с++ (ха-ха). Естественно, что в процессе изучения встал вопрос синхронизации потоков. Ситуация: Поток T1 запускает Поток T2 и ждет его завершения. Поток T2 в свою очередь висит 2 секунды и потом завершается. И есть целая пачка способов для синхронизации потоков. Меня заинтересовали два из них, которые описаны в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350473/why-do-i-need-stdcondition-variable) ответе.

В первом случае в цикле ожидания используется std::this_thread::yield(). В [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) сказано, что yield() позволяет другим потокам выполняться, пока вызывающий поток ждет. То есть по идее, используя yield() в цикле мы не должны тратить впустую процессорное время на бесполезное ожидание - в это время выполняются другие потоки.

Вопрос: Если это верно, то зачем тогда нужен std::condition_variable, который по сути делает то же самое, и почему в ответе выше говорится, что в первом случае процессор был загружен на 90%?

Comment: Это `std::condition_variable::wait` заставляет уснуть поток T1 до тех пор, пока второй поток T2 не просигнализирует, что хватит спать (либо не случится ложное пробуждение). А вот `yield` не усыпляет текущий поток T1, а просто просит планировщик ОС поставить его в конец очереди готовых к выполнению потоков. Т.к. второй поток ничего не делает, а просто спит, то ОС снова запускает первый поток, и он снова просится в конец очереди и т.д. Это бессмысленное перемещение по очереди потоков и загружает процессор на 99%.

Comment: @wololo спасибо большое, неправильно понял суть функции. Вы мне помогли)

Comment: @wololo в таком случае другой вопрос. Имеет ли смысл перед std::condition_variable::wait вызывать yield?

Comment: Вряд ли. Вызов `std::condition_variable::wait` сделает всё необходимое. Зачем перед ним ещё вызывать `yield`? Чтобы дать ресурсов второму потоку? Но `wait` и так сообщает, что первому потоку пока что ресурсы не нужны. К тому же в момент вызова `yield` второй поток уже может ожидать разблокировки мьютекса. Т.е. мы дадим ресурсов второму потоку, но он не может сделать ничего полезного — мьютекс то заблокирован. А вот `wait` освободит мьютес.

Comment: Еще один способ забыли: модный-молодежный `.wait()` на `std::atomic_bool`. Упрощенная замена `condition_variable`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, прикольная штука. Надо будет запомнить. Но пока что я сделал свой примитив синхронизации, который инкапсулирует в себе логику работы с condition_variable